# Displaying the Choices Field in human readable format

Tags: python, django

In the webpage this renders as

Status: i

How do i display the long name "Initiated" in the django template?

In my Template

```
<p>Status: {{ transaction.status }}</p>
```

models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    creator = models.SlugField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 999,decimal_places =2,null= True,default=0)
    accepted_by = models.SlugField()
    oferto_slug = models.SlugField()
    STATUSES = (
        ('i', 'Initiated'),
        ('a', 'Accepted'),
        ('d', 'Delivered'),
        ('c', 'Cancelled'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUSES, default='i',max_length=10)


views.py
 def __init__():
    self.state = 'i'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your template, try this instead:

```
<p>Status: {{ transaction.get_status_display }}</p>
```

You simply add the qualified field name between `get_` and `_display`. (There is no need for parentheses after the method name in the template.) This will give you access to the human readable form.

See [the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).